# Django: How to Access Installed Third Party App's Model and Data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, workflow, django-river

I have been using django-river(https://github.com/javrasya/django-river) application within my app (https://github.com/rupin/WorkflowEngine)

I have used the Django rest framework in my application and would like to get the data from the django-river tables. The name of the table is State.

My serializer is as follows

```
from river.models import State
from rest_framework import serializers

class StateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ['id', 'label']
```

Also, my API view is as follows

```
from rest_framework import generics
from workflowengine.riverserializers.StateSerializer import StateSerializer
from river.models import State

class StateList(generics.ListAPIView):  

    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return State.objects.all()
```

Through the Admin console, I have added 11 states inside my state table, which I have checked with pgadmin.

When i access the API through the browser, I get 11 empty sections in my API ( no error, just the data is missing).

[image]

I cant seem to understand how the 11 data points presented in the API are empty. That it presented 11 elements, but no data, which is pretty weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```